# By clicking on the toggle, the page does not adjust

Tags: css

I have a table in my HTML page

[image]

When I click on the toggle

[image]

I would like the table or the form to be readjusted, do you think it is possible to do this in CSS?

I can share you my code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ddyolq?file=src/app/admin/admin.component.html), I think it's easier to understand.

admin.component.html

```
  <div class="header"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu" />
  <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
    <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
  </label>
  <div id="sidebarMenu">
    <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
      <li>
        <a routerLink="index"> <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Index </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

index.component.html

```
<div style="padding-top: 50px ">
  <h1 style=" padding-top: 15px; text-align: center">Indices boursiers</h1>

  <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 90%;  ">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr style="color: red">
          <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Indice</th>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Place</th>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Cours</th>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Variation</th>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Date et heure</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" style="text-align:center">AED / EUR</th>
          <td style="text-align: center">Euronext Amsterdam</td>
          <td style="text-align: center">1 134,65</td>
          <td style="text-align: center">0,31 %</td>
          <td style="text-align: center">08/11 - 10:04</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" style="text-align:center">ARS / EUR</th>
          <td style="text-align: center">Euronext Amsterdam</td>
          <td style="text-align: center">1 134,65</td>
          <td style="text-align: center">0,31 %</td>
          <td style="text-align: center">08/11 - 10:04</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" style="text-align:center">ATS / EUR</th>
          <td style="text-align: center">Euronext Amsterdam</td>
          <td style="text-align: center">1 081,24</td>
          <td style="text-align: center">0,59 %</td>
          <td style="text-align: center">08/11 - 10:04</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

styles.css

```
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

.header {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.mainInner {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainInner div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1.25px;
}

#sidebarMenu {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 310px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  transform: translateX(-310px);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.sidebarMenuInner {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.sidebarMenuInner li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.sidebarMenuInner li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.sidebarMenuInner li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ #sidebarMenu {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

.sidebarIconToggle {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 22px;
  left: 15px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

.spinner {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.diagonal.part-1 {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: 8px;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  margin-top: -9px;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Thank you so much for your help and your explanation.

Comment: Yes it is possible with CSS, try to put your table in a 100% area and when something toggle reduce that area to 70%(or anything u want) and give 30% area to the menu

Comment: @Rana: This code does not come from me, I do not understand what to modify? Which class?